# In iPad/iPhone (iOS 17.4) App crashed on Launching

Tags: ios, objective-c, firebase, wkwebview, launch

I am facing an issue when ever I am trying to install app on iOS 17.4 app getting crashed on Launching. Crash occurred in FIRDLJavaScriptExecutor file and I also update the firebase pods to latest version. Even also getting same crashed.

[image]

Getting this error.

Comment: Where you are loading the `WKWebView`

Comment: Actually this occurred in FIRDLJavaScriptExecutor file that is Pod file. whenever I trying to launch app on iOS 17.4 Devices this has been crashed.

Comment: Instead of adding screenshots of your code, please add the actual code to the question. To capture the error message, right click on the red indicator and "Reveal in Issue Navigator".